# JavaFX combobox is calling listcell.updateitem infinitely

Tags: java, javafx, view, combobox

I am trying to make a combobox with large number of items(more than 10000). It initializes without problem. But when i click it, it just freezes. For debugging i created my own listCell and followed the updateitem function. When i click, it's calling updateitem infinitely. Shouldn't it update only visible items ? Here is an example controller:

```
   package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    ComboBox comboBox1;

    public final class ExampleCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

        Label myLabel;

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item,empty);
            System.out.println("update");
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if(myLabel==null){
                    myLabel=new Label((String)item);

                }else{
                    myLabel.setText((String)item);}
                setGraphic(myLabel);
            }
        }
    }
    public void initialize(){

    for(int i =0;i<10000;i++){
        comboBox1.getItems().add("example");
    }
    comboBox1.setCellFactory(param -> new ExampleCell<>());
   }
}
```

And my fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          prefWidth="500"
          prefHeight="500"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <ComboBox
            fx:id="comboBox1"
    />
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Just pass the string `m.getAdd()` and create the `Label` inside the `ListCell` This will probably help some. That way instead of creating 10000 `Label`, you will only create the amount shown in your `ListView`.

Comment: Are you doing anything special with the `Label`? If not, why even use it.

Comment: Your cell factory is iterating through all the items. So every time it needs a *single cell*,  it is creating 10,000 labels...

Comment: Also, it doesn't really make sense to add labels (or any UI component) to a combo box's items list. You should be adding `data`, not UI components.

Comment: Can't tell from the code you posted. Create a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D I edited my question. Thank you for your interest

Comment: Yeah. That's... interesting. I have no idea why it's doing that. It seems to call `updateItem()` 4 times for every item at startup, and four times for every item when the combo popup is displayed. That looks like a bug. (Though, it has to be pointed out, a combo box with 10,000 items is really quite unusable, so an argument that this is not a supported use case would be hard to refute.)

Comment: @James_D actually it's doing the same thing even with 100 items. I think the number of items is not the problem

Comment: Except that with 100 items it's going to happen quickly enough to not matter...

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that it doesn't create many cells (only 14 when I ran it); it just updates them a whole bunch of times. That's at least consistent with the intention, even if it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: My best guess is that it's trying to compute the width of the combo box, based on the width of the widest cell that could be displayed.

Comment: @James_D spot on - it's indeed the width measuring ... by default is measuring all items, limiting that was intended to go into public api but never made it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is indeed the measuring of pref widths for all cells, as (not publicly!) documented in ComboBoxListViewSkin:

```
// By default we measure the width of all cells in the ListView. If this
// is too burdensome, the developer may set a property in the ComboBox
// properties map with this key to specify the number of rows to measure.
// This may one day become a property on the ComboBox itself.
private static final String COMBO_BOX_ROWS_TO_MEASURE_WIDTH_KEY = "comboBoxRowsToMeasureWidth";
```

The way out is to limit the number of rows that should be measured - no guarantee, as no public doc is no specification at all:

```
comboBox1.getProperties().put("comboBoxRowsToMeasureWidth", 10);
```

Still calling the updateItem a lot initially, that is at least twice the given limit during the measuring (filling and releasing) plus once for setting the actual value.